# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. Problem with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, conda

Whenever I am trying to plot the history of a model my kernel outputs this error.

> Error: "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

It only occurs when I am trying to plot the history of any model otherwise matplotlib.pyplot works perfectly.
I have tried `conda install freetype=2.10.4` but didn't get any positive results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After investing a lot I found that matplotlib.pyplot isn't installed properly on the current env. Creating a new env and then installing the library, resolved my problem.